# Build C# cross referenced projects

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am writing a game which consists of two projects in a solution:

**Engine.csproj** The actual executeable, holding all my core engine code.

**Content.csproj** A library which holds the specifics of my game. It references *Engine* using a `<ProjectReference>` to access the engine functionality.

On startup, the *Content.dll* is loaded by the *Engine* process.

For ease of development I want to just press play in my IDE and have the following done:

1. Engine.csproj gets built
2. Content.csproj gets built
3. Engine.exe starts

I tried also referencing the Content.csproj in Engine.csproj, but that causes a cross dependency, which causes the building process to just loop forever.

The current bandaid is a "Before launch" setting in my Rider IDE. That sadly does not work for my colleagues who mostly use Visual Studio. So a non-ide-specific fix is needed.

Comment: If Engine is the one loading Content, which makes sense for a game, then it needs to reference it, not the other way around like you're doing right now. If there are common things that both Engine and Content need, put that in a third project and reference it from both.

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve circular dependencies like this is to introduce interfaces. Create a third library, containing interfaces for all your engine classes. This can be referenced from both your projects, is implemented by your engine, and used by your game. This way your library do not have to reference your engine project directly.

However, I would consider reversing the dependency, and have the engine as a library and your game as the exe-project. The engine will likely be much easier to reuse if it is a library.

If you are not planning on reusing the engine you could just consider putting everything into the same project, but different namespaces.

Comment: That would be incredibly difficult and time consuming, especially after already getting close to 100k lines. Sadly not really feasable for us.

Comment: The cost of changing Engine to a library and Content to an exe is an edit in each of the project files and is independent of the number of lines of code. Ther cost of moving all the files into one project is likewise independent of the number of lines of code.

Comment: I was refering to the proposal of adding an API project. 

What you're proposing here sadly isn't an option aswell, as the engine should also be able to be its standalone thing. I didn't specify that in my original post. Sorry for that.

Comment: @DavidKlostermann It sounds like you have built yourself into a corner. So you either need to resort to a hack as you do now (maybe VS post build script?), or spend the time and effort on improving the architecture.

Comment: @DavidKlostermann You also mention that the engine should be standalone. But just having it in a separate project does not mean it can be reused for anything else. If you are developing the engine together with the game, chances are they are so tightly coupled that it will be impossible to write any other game without rewriting the engine, and that any changes to the engine will not be backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

~~I assume that Engine.csproj has a `ProjectReference` to Content.csproj. In your description it is flipped. (The .exe project should have the `ProjectReference` indicating that it depends on the .dll project.)~~

**[Update]**

- Engine.csproj builds an .exe.
- Content.csproj builds a .dll.
- Content.csproj has a `ProjectReference` to Engine. The .exe is copied to the output of the Content project.
- When the .exe is run, it tries to dynamically load `Content.dll` via `Assembly.LoadFile()`.

### In Visual Studio:

In the 'Tools' menu, choose 'Options...'. In 'Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run', verify that the value of 'On Run, when projects are out of date:' is not 'Never build'. The default is 'Always build'.

In the Solution Explorer, right-click the Engine project and choose 'Set as Startup Project'.

In the 'Debug' menu, choose 'Start Without Debugging'. This will run the startup project (Engine). If Engine or its dependency of Content are out of date, a build will be performed before running.

**[Update]**

Neither project will work as a startup project. Instead, in the Content project create a 'debug launch profile'. Choose the 'executable' type to specify running the engine.exe.

### Non-IDE specific:

MSBuild is a build engine, not a general scripting tool.

I'd suggest creating a PowerShell script that executes MSBuild to build the solution and then executes your enigne.exe executable.

From within Visual Studio and from within Rider, the PowerShell script could be executed in a number of ways including running from the terminal window.

Comment: Your assumption is not true. Content.csproj is the actual game, where Engine.csproj is the underlying framework. Therefore it only makes sense to me that Content has a reference to Engine to make use of its logic.

Comment: You stated that Engine is the .exe and that "On startup, the Content.dll is loaded by the Engine process". Is that incorrect? How are you executing your game? What is your command line for running the game?

Comment: By "Content has a reference to Engine", do you mean a `using` statement? A `using` and a `ProjectReference` are very different.

Comment: Yes, on startup a Content.dll is loaded using Assembly.LoadFile(). 
Yes I meant a `ProjectReference`. There isn't (and can't be) a single `using` that refers to the Content in my Engine.

Comment: Ah. You are dynamically loading the DLL. An important detail. Your scenario makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: Added updates to the answer.